# Release app before release date

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have uploaded a new app to iTunes connect and set the release date to 20th January, as content for the app is retrieved from a webserver and I didn't think the website would be complete until this date.

However I'm ready to release the application to the app store now but cant find a way of doing so, I have gone into 'Rights and Pricing' and changed the availability date to today but my app status is still 'Ready for Sale' and nothing else has changed.

How can I release my app before my scheduled release date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done. and I was correct in the way I did it above, however Apple don't give you any message to say it will be released early or that your changes have been saved or anything.

It was live this morning in the app store!